# Changing the result into the list

Tags: python

Do you have any sugesstions that would be helpful for me to print this result using a list with more efficient way??

```
result = list(i for i in range(1, 101))

numbers = [int(x) for x in result]
mylist =[]

for m in result:
    if m % 3 == 0:
        mylist.append(str("Fizz"))
    if m % 5 == 0:
        mylist.append(str("Buzz"))
    if m % 15 == 0:
        mylist.append(str("FizzBuzz"))
    else:
        mylist.append(str(m))

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
def filter(value):
    for x, y in zip(('FizzBuzz', 'Buzz', 'Fizz'), (15, 5, 3)):
        if value % y == 0:
            return x
    return value


print(list(map(filter, range(1, 101))))
```

Comment: Thank you it is really nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist =[]

for m in range(1,101):
    if m % 3 == 0:
        mylist.append(str("Fizz"))
    elif m % 5 == 0:
        mylist.append(str("Buzz"))
    elif m % 15 == 0:
        mylist.append(str("FizzBuzz"))
    else:
        mylist.append(str(m))

print(mylist)
```

To improve code efficiency, you can use elif
Also I don't see numbers being used.
As you multiple conditions, I don't think we can shorten the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have implemented this:

```
mylist = []
for m in range(1, 101):
    if m % 3 == 0:
        mylist.append("Fizz")
    if m % 5 == 0:
        mylist.append("Buzz")
    if m % 15 == 0:
        mylist.append("FizzBuzz")
    else:
        mylist.append(str(m))
print(mylist)
```

While you may have intended to implement this:

```
mylist = []
for m in range(1, 101):
    if m % 15 == 0:
        mylist.append("FizzBuzz")
    elif m % 3 == 0:
        mylist.append("Fizz")
    elif m % 5 == 0:
        mylist.append("Buzz")
    else:
        mylist.append(str(m))
print(mylist)
```

The answers to both are different.

Comment: For example, lets say m = 15. Then in your code the first, second and third if conditions are all met, since m is divisible by 3,5 and 15. So for m=15 all 3 "Fizz", "Buzz" and "FizzBuzz" will be appended to the list.

Comment: In my latter code, at m=15 the first condition will be met as m is divisble by 15. Then the code moves past the elif and else conditions and onto m=16. Note that the order of conditions matter. So currently at m=15 only "FizzBuzz" will be appended. However, if I had set my first condition as: if m % 3 == 0, then only "Fizz" would have been appended